# Query Statistics in management data warehouse empty

Tags: sql-server, management-data-warehouse

i am using management data warehouse form SQL Server 2012.

I used it before on a 2008 instance a few years ago and everything worked good. 
However this time i cannot see any Query Stastics data meaning the in built report is empty.

The Collector is configured and running.
The SQL Server agent Job is collecting and uploading and does not fail.

However still i cannot see any queries and there are plenty of them running on that server.

Does my service account has no rights? What permissions does it need?

I want to mention that for "Server Activity" and "Disk Usage" Report i have no problem and i can see proper values.

Comment: Do the upload jobs succeed? Does the `snapshots.query_stats` in the `sysutility_mdw` database contain anything?

Comment: The upload job succeeds and the table snapshots.query_stats is empty.
But i don't use sysutility_mdw i use the old management data warehouse that i crated with rightclick on "data collection" create management data warehouse.

Comment: Try enabling additional logging for dcexec: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2011/07/13/enabling-additional-tracing-for-data-collector/

Comment: thanks i did this but it seems everything works fine, package finishes with "succeeded" and  i cannot see any warning or error.

what system management view does the package use to trace query statistics ?

Comment: I reads `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and other exec DMOs. It doesn't read `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` as you would expect. The actual query can be found inspecting the collection package in msdb.